# List comments by number of likes

Tags: php, mysql, comments, facebook-like

I'm trying to get PHP to list out comments by descending number of likes they receive.

Currently, the comments' content and the number of likes they receive are in 2 separate tables: "comments" and "likes".

PHP code:

To get comments from "comments" table:

```
$this->db->order_by ('comment_id', 'asc');
$data['comment'] = $this->db->select()->get('comment');
```

To get likes from "likes" table:

```
$data['like'] = $this->db->get('like');
```

To show the number of likes for each comment:

```
$query_like=$this->db->query("select ip from like where comment_id='$comment_id'");
$count_like=$query_like->num_rows();
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to order the comments by the number of likes they receive without changing the tables' structure. Any advice hugely appreciated.

Comment: `innoDB` with `foreign key`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the data structure correctly, you just need a `join` and an aggregation:

```
select c.*, count(*) as numlikes
from comments c join
     upvote l
     on c.comment_id = l.comment_id
group by c.comment_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

EDIT:

To get comments with zero upvotes, do the `left outer join` in the other direction:

```
SELECT c.*, count(u.comment_id) as num_upvotes
FROM comment c left join
     upvote u
     on c.comment_id = u.comment_id
WHERE c.comment_id = '$interview_id'
GROUP BY c.comment_id
ORDER BY num_upvotes DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. What does "select c.*" mean? Tried looking it up but couldn't find results.

Comment: The `c` and `l` are table aliases.  These are shorter names for tables and are required for self-joins and for subqueries (in many databases).  In general, they also make queries easier to read.  That means "get all the fields from the table with the alias `c`".

Comment: Thank you. My understanding is this: I would select all fields from the table with alias C, which is table "comments", then I join this table with "like", where I get the fields where the comment id from "like" equals to the comment id in "comments". Then I would group them by comment_id, and order by the ip for. Is my understanding correct? And, how could I order them by the number of ip/like? Thanks.

Comment: @user3192948 . . . By saying `order by count(*) desc` or `order by numlikes desc` (as the query in the answer now does).

Comment: Thanks again. And forgive me for asking dumb questions. I tried the following: $data['comment']=
  "select c.*, 
  count (*) as numlikes
  from 'comment' c join 'upvote' l
  on c.comment_id=l.comment_id
  group by c.comment_id order by count (*) desc;";
and when I do:
  print_r($data['comment']);
  die; it does not show the value of the query but rather the entire text after "=" sign. Did I do not enter the mysql code correctly?

Comment: @user3192948 . . . `count()` is not valid SQL.  You need a constant, column name, or `*` between the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the table name from "like" to "upvote and finally got it to work. Here's my code: $query=$this->db->query
  ("SELECT c.*, count(*) as num_upvotes
  FROM upvote as u
  LEFT JOIN comment c on c.comment_id = u.comment_id
  GROUP BY c.comment_id 
  ORDER BY num_upvotes
  DESC");

Comment: My following question is that I would like to apply a further criteria to the comments being displayed. Each comment has a corresponding "interview_id" which states which interview the comment is under. I tried this but it says the SQL syntax is wrong. Where to fix? Thanks again: $interview_id = $this->uri->segment(3);   $query=$this->db->query
  ("SELECT c.*, count(*) as num_upvotes
  FROM upvote as u
  LEFT JOIN comment c on c.comment_id = u.comment_id
  GROUP BY c.comment_id 
  ORDER BY num_upvotes where c.comment_id='$interview_id'
  DESC");

Comment: @user3192948 . . . Put the `where` before the `group by`.

Comment: It did work for comments that have corresponding upvotes. Thanks a lot. However now comments with 0 upvote are not displaying. I'm trying to think how to solve this. Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: For now the table "upvote" does not record comments without upvotes since no upvote is made for them. Would it be better to have the "upvote" table record comments with no upvote, or there's a way to tweak our code so it list out first those that have upvotes, then those without upvotes?